# Nested while loop executing top loop before nested loop completes- Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-loops, do-while

I'm working on a Connect Four game exercise. Everything is working except error checking.  The user inputs a string, and I need to check first if it is the right length and format (nested while-loop), and then if the entry creates a winner to end the game (top while-loop).

However, even if the entry isn't valid, and the nested while-loop should still be looping, Java executes the rest of the code in the outer while-loop. What am I doing wrong here?

```
while (true) {
    // get row and column from user
    int row=1, column=1;
    boolean validr = false, validc = false;
    do {
        System.out.print("Type the row and column you would like to drop your chip, separated by a space: ");
        String drop = keyboard.nextLine();

        // check that input is proper length
        if(drop.length() == 3 && drop.contains(" ")) {
            int space = drop.indexOf(" ");

            // check if row is integer
            try { 
                int testrow = Integer.parseInt(drop.substring(0, space));
                //check if between 1 and 6
                if (testrow > 0 && testrow < 7) {
                    row = Integer.parseInt(drop.substring(0, space));
                    validr = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Whoops, that row isn't valid!");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Make sure you're typing valid row and column numbers!");
            }

            // check if column is valid
            try {
                int testcolumn = Integer.parseInt(drop.substring(space+1));
                //check if between 1 and 7
                if (testcolumn > 0 && testcolumn < 8) {
                    column = Integer.parseInt(drop.substring(space+1));
                    validc = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Whoops, that column isn't valid!");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Make sure you're typing valid row and column numbers!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Remember, type the row number, followed by a space, and then the column number.");
        }
    } while (!validr && !validc);

    // change selected array value to 'x'
    board[row-1][column-1] = "x";

    // check if there is now a winner

    if (checkBoard(board) == true) {
        printBoard(board);
        System.out.println("Congratulations!  You got four in a row!");
        break;
    }
    else {
        printBoard(board);
    }
}
```

It will display the error message for whichever exception was thrown, but it will also change `board[1][1]` to "x" and start over at the top of the whole code pasted here, instead of just the top of the nested while-loop.

Comment: _Everything is working except error checking_ doesn't provide much information, can you provide some input where you don't get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
 while (!validr && !validc);
```

condition means that the inner loop will continue as long as both `validr` and `validc` are false (i.e. both the row number and column number are invalid).

You need both `validr` and `validc` to be true in order to exit the inner loop, so your condition should be :

```
while (!validr || !validc);
```

i.e. the loop will continue as long as either `validr` or `validc` is false.

Comment: Thank you!! I spent so much time thinking about what was wrong *inside* the loop that I forgot to check the loop conditions!

Answer (score 0):

!(a&b)= !a || !b
"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"

Demorgan's law.
Applying this on your program your while loop should be

```
while (!validr || !validc);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I spent so much time thinking about what was wrong inside the loop that I forgot to check the loop conditions!